# Does a page's access token stay if I have offline access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a Rails 3 app that allows users to post to their FB page via email and text message. I'm getting both offline access and page management permissions.

I'm aware that a page access token is required to update a business page. I'd like to be avoid having to loop through pages and get the page access token every time.

So, my question is: **can I save the page's access token initially and reliably use it for updates?**

Answer (score 0):

As long as you go through scenario 5 (Page Access Tokens) https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/, you should be able to obtain a page token that doesn't expire.

> By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User
>   ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not
>   expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when
>   querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the
>   deprecated offline_access permission.

You also don't have to go through the `/me/accounts` you can use `/page_id?fields=access_token`